# Accessing elements in GLKQuaternion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert the following code from Java into Objective-c.

How can I create a new Quaternion object like I do in Java without creating my own Quaternion class. Is it possible to use GLKQuaternion seeing as this is already implemented?

```
this.q = new Quaternion(qrot);
```

Secondly, How can I access elements from a GLKQuaternion struct. I have tried for example:

```
self._m[9]
```

With little luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm reading this right, but for part 1, you are talking about constructors in Java, with params.  To my knowledge, Objective-C does not use constructors.  To mimic one, you have to expand the `init` method. So,

```
this.q = new Quaternion(qrot);
```

becomes

```
self.q = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithRotation:qrot];
```

For part 2, accessing `struct` elements in Objective-C does use dot notation like in Java, but unless the variable _m is an array, your code would cause compile errors.

where `structElement` is an `int = y`,

```
exmapleStruct.strutElement = 9;
```

is a a valid argument.  In your code, you're accessing `_m` sub 9, or the 8th element in the array `_m`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. You have answered my question perfectly. Kind Regards, Sam

Comment: Remember to use the `self` keyword instead of `this`

Comment: Will I need to create my own Quaternion class or can I make an object using GLKQuaternion. For instance will GLKQuaternion *example = [GLKQuaternion alloc] init] be enough or will I need my own class such as Quaternion *example = [Quaternion alloc] init]?

Comment: GLKQuarternion is a structure, not a class, so you cannot make object from it.  To initialize an example `struct` you can use, for example: `GLKQuaternion GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis (
   float radians,
   float x,
   float y,
   float z
);`.  What you could do instead is make a new type of object then that uses GLKQuarternion structs as a variable.  Here's some good documentation: [Apple Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKQuaternion/Reference/reference.html)